# Batch file variable in an environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a program named `go.exe`, and I pass it a file name `example` so that it can make a log file named `example_golog.txt`.

The problem here is that I want to only call the executable without explicitly giving a filename or making a user have to give a file name.

My solution to this was to name a system variable called `GO` whose value is `go.exe %~n0`. What's wrong with this is instead of the `%~n0` part getting the file name of the batch file that called it, my `go.exe` file just makes a text file called `%~n0_golog.txt`.

Is there any way around this so that `%~n0` will do it's magic in the batch files that call it in `go.exe %~n0`?

EDIT:

My system variable:
Name: `GO`
Value: `go %~n0`

My `test.bat` file:

```
@echo on
%GO% 
pause
```

When I run `test.bat`, the `%~n0` does not expand out.

So instead of `test_golog.txt` being made, `%~n0_golog.txt` is made

Comment: That argument should always expand even if it was empty from shifting.  Could please show us all the relevant code.

Comment: @Squashman added some more. Any idea?

Comment: If your environment variable %GO% worked as you want it to, how would it look being used in your batch file?

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  You set it as a variable before you started the batch file. Why don't you just set it in the batch file?

Comment: @lyst %GO% would be `go %~n0` which would expand out to `go test` if the batch file that ran it is named `test.bat`

Comment: Not really understanding why you are doing it this way.  In your batch file you could just have: `go.exe %~n0`.  Why are you setting it as an environmental variable before you execute the batch file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your batch file, you can `call` it to dereference the variable.

`echo %go%` will report `go %~n0`.

`call echo %go%` will report `go test` (from a batch file named test).

You can use whatever other sets you need from there.

Comment: This will not execute go.exe and expand the %~n0 to the batch file name.  The CALL ECHO trick works because it is expanding the variables twice. But it will not expand %~n0 when removing the ECHO.  You would need to put this into a FOR /F command to capture the output and then execute that macro variable.

Comment: @Squashman Thats not quite right, Call %go% will execute the content of the var Go with %~n0 expanded to the current batch file name, no need for for /f. But I agree the construct is a bit weird

Comment: @LotPings, I tested by setting `set go=find.exe "%~n0" %0` and sure enough it works.  I have no idea why!  You never see %0 get expanded at all.  Seriously confused by this one.